# How to view input based on if condition in PHP MySQLi

Tags: php, html, mysql

How to make the if statement, if the the post belongs to the user, then only the owner of the post has a `like`/`view`/`edit`/`delete` button available. If the post does not belong to the user, it only displays `like` and `view` buttons.

```
<?php
$get_post = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$run_post = mysqli_query($connect, $get_post);
if($run_post && mysqli_num_rows($run_post) > 0)
{
    while($row_post = mysqli_fetch_array($run_post))
    {
        $post_title  = $row_post['post_title'];
        $get_user    = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
        $run_user    = mysqli_query($connect, $get_user);
        $check_user  = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);
        $user_name   = $check_user['name'];
        $user_images = $check_user['images'];

        echo "<div id='post_wrap'>
            <p>$post_title</p>
            <a href=''><button>Like</button></a>
            <a href=''><button>View</button></a>
            <a href=''><button>Delete</button></a>
            <a href=''><button>Edit</button></a>
            </div>";
    }
    mysqli_free_result($run_post);
}
else
{
    echo "No post yet";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please post database details. (column names)

Comment: users table (user_id, name, email) , posts (post_id, user_id, title)

Answer (score 2):

You have to store `user_id` as a session value. Then you can checked current user posts this way, `$_SESSION['user_id'] == $row_post['user_id']`

```
 echo "<div id='post_wrap'>
           <p>$post_title</p>
           <a href=''><button>Like</button></a>
           <a href=''><button>View</button></a>";
           if($_SESSION['user_id'] == $row_post['user_id']){
                  echo "<a href=''><button>Delete</button></a>
                        <a href=''><button>Edit</button></a>";
            }            

     echo "</div>";
```

Comment: how you get current user id, have you used sessions?

Comment: i use 'email' column field in the table as session

Comment: you have to store user_id also as session.

Comment: i can echo the value of 'email' session . but when i try to add if statement inside echo "" . it didnt work at all . :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125986/discussion-between-user3099298-and-rozaimi).

Answer (score 0):

Please check following answer.

```
                 $html = "<a href=''><button>Like</button></a>
                            <a href=''><button>View</button></a>";
                if($user_id == $row_post['user_id']){
                   $html .= "<a href=''><button>Delete</button></a>
                         <a href=''><button>Edit</button></a>"
                }            
  echo $html;
```

Comment: thanks . let me try the code first :) . i'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

Use Following, check if user id and database id are same so that will add extra HTML in `$login_user` else will be empty. And echo `$login_user` in your View.

```
<?php

    $get_post = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    $run_post = mysqli_query($connect, $get_post);
        if($run_post && mysqli_num_rows($run_post) > 0 )
        {
            while($row_post = mysqli_fetch_array($run_post))
            {
                $post_title      = $row_post['post_title'];

                $get_user   =  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
                $run_user   = mysqli_query($connect, $get_user);
                $check_user = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);

                    $user_name  = $check_user['name'];
                    $user_images = $check_user['images'];   

                    $login_user = ($user_id == $row_post['user_id'])? "<a href=''><button>Delete</button></a>
                                    <a href=''><button>Edit</button></a>": "";
                        echo "<div id='post_wrap'>
                                    <p>$post_title</p>
                                    <a href=''><button>Like</button></a>
                                    <a href=''><button>View</button></a>".
                                $login_user . "
                                </div>";
            }
            mysqli_free_result($run_post);          
        }
    else
    {
        echo "No post yet";
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply :) . but i use 'email' field column in database as $session . but thanks. i'll try your suggestion first .. see if its work or not .

Comment: hye . thanks for the response . :) . it's ok . i already found the solutions . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120634/how-to-create-if-statement-inside-echo-in-php-mysqli/40120664#40120664