# How to create if statement inside echo in PHP MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to ask,

I have two tables , **users** and **posts** with column field

**users** : user_id, name, email

**posts** : post_id, user_id, post_title

I want to **display all posts from all users**,

but I want only **logged_in user session** to have another two extra button while other public posts only have two button

p/s : I used **email** column field in users table as login **$_SESSION**.

```
<?php 
    global $connect;
    global $user_id;

    $sql_post = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    $run_post = mysqli_query($connect, $sql_post);

    if($run_post && mysqli_num_rows($run_post) > 0 )
    {
        while($row_post = mysqli_fetch_array($run_post))
        {
            $post_id    = $row_post['post_id'];
            $user_id    = $row_post['user_id'];
            $post_title = $row_post['post_title'];

            $sql_user   =  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
            $run_user   = mysqli_query($connect, $sql_user);
            $check_user = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);

                    $user_id     = $check_user['user_id'];
                    $user_name   = $check_user['name'];
                    $user_email  = $check_user['email'];

                    $post_output = "<div id='posts_wrap'>
                                        <p>$user_name</p>
                                        <p>$user_email</p>
                                        <p>$post_title</p>
                                        <a href=''><button>Like</button></a>
                                        <a href=''><button>Comment</button></a> 

                                            // i want these two button (Edit and Delete) only available to logged in user
                                            <a href=''><button>Edit</button></a>
                                            <a href=''><button>Delete</button></a>  
                                    </div>
                                   ";
                    echo $post_output;
        }
        mysqli_free_result($run_post);          
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No post yet";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After user loggine keep user detail in session and check condition if user logged in or not For example if you are trying to comment and like only for logged in user then you can do somethink like

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['email']='email@example.com';
$user_name='dd';
$user_email='ddd';
$post_title='gsdg';

$post_output = "<div id='posts_wrap'><p>$user_name</p><p>$user_email</p><p>$post_title</p>";
 if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){ 
        $post_output.="<a href=''><button>Like</button></a><a href=''><button>Comment</button></a> ";
    }  
    // i want these two button (Edit and Delete) only available to logged in user
    $post_output.= "<a href=''><button>Edit</button></a><a href=''><button>Delete</button></a> </div>";                                    
            print_r($post_output);      





?>
```

in the above code user is logged in so all buttons are visible .if not then its not visible to all .just try to destroy session.i think previous session email still there

Comment: hye , thanks for the prompt response :) . let me try the code first  . i'll let you know later . thanks again :)

Comment: @Rozaimi.keep in mind once user logged in you have to keep email in session

Comment: i notice that <?php if($_SESSION['email']){ ?> code inside $post_output still blend inside "" as i paste the code inside notepad++ .

Comment: @Rozaimi.Updated answer please check

Comment: the code not working :( .. all user still display the button inside if statement inside $post_output

Comment: thanks :) . let me try your suggestion code first . i'll let you know later .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126055/discussion-between-rozaimi-and-icoders).

Answer (score -1):

i found the solutions . it turns out that i need to create another query and **combine the user_id and email** to makesure the login is belong to the loggedin user. here's the code

```
<?php
    global $connect;
    global $user_id;

        $get_post = "SELECT * FROM posts";
        $run_post = mysqli_query($connect, $get_post);

        if($run_post && mysqli_num_rows($run_post) > 0 )
        {
            while($row_post = mysqli_fetch_array($run_post))
            {
            $post_id         = $row_post['post_id'];
            $user_id         = $row_post['user_id'];
            $post_title      = $row_post['post_title'];

            $emailsql    = $_SESSION['email'];
            $get_email   =  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND email='$emailsql'";
            $run_email   = mysqli_query($connect, $get_email);
            $check_email = mysqli_fetch_array($run_email);

                $d_email = $check_email['email'];

            $get_user   =  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
            $run_user   = mysqli_query($connect, $get_user);
            $check_user = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);

                    $user_id     = $check_user['user_id'];
                    $user_name   = $check_user['name'];

                    echo    "<div id='posts_wrap'>
                                <p><h3><a href='userprofile.php?user_id=$user_id'>$user_name</a></h3></p>

                                <div id='posts_title'>
                                <p><h3><a href='post.php?post_id=$post_id'>$post_title</a></h3></p>
                                </div>

                                <hr>
                                <a href=''><button>Like</button></a>
                                <a href=''><button>Comment</button></a>
                                ";

                                if($check_email){
                                    echo "
                                    <a href=''><button>Edit</button></a>
                                    <a href=''><button>Delete</button></a>";
                                }

                    echo    "</div>";
            }
            mysqli_free_result($run_post);          
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No post yet";
        }   
?>
```